# c++ decide an array size with variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array inside a class which is:

```
private:
    static const int MAX_EQUIPS=100;
    equip a_t[MAX_EQUIPS];
    int a_n;
```

Then in the main they tell me what MAX_EQUIPS size should be, how can I put it so it changes? It starts at X but then it increases or decreases when the new valor is entered.

Comment: If it changes, it isn't `const`, is it? Use a `vector`.

Comment: I do not think the OP means the length of the array changes at runtime, but rather that in main() somehow he gets a value and that value dictates the size of the array

Comment: @stijn exactly, I need to put a size before running it but then when they tell me what size it actually is I need to change it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring to [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which are not permitted in C++. many possible alternatives exist, for instance you can use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 1):

A c++ solution would be:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass( size_t n ) :
    a_t( n )
  {
  }

private:
  std::vector< int > a_t;
};
```

Comment: I've tried this and either I don't know how to adapt it to my code or it doesn't work. When I do it it keeps saying MAX_EQUIPS isn't declared and I can't use the vector anymore in the same class

Comment: Please post an update with the code you're trying to use then - the example above should wor, and basic vector access semantics are like array semantics, that is you can use a_t[ 0 ] etc.

Comment: Oops sry, I finished it last night and I didn't remember to post it. I didn't change the array size in the end, I created a new variable that I used for a different array size and worked with that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using std::vector for this, as it will wrap most of this itself.

```
private:
    std::vector<int> a_t;
```

Then when you're given the size:
    a_t.resize(MAX_EQUIPS);

Your a_n will be a_t.size().

However, if you **Really** want to do it yourself, you'll need to do some allocation (which you should tie to ctor/dtor semantics.